# makefile variables within variables executing bash scripts

Tags: bash, makefile, toolchain, go-toolchain

I have a `makefile` that I want to run against both linux (debian/Ubuntu) and Windows/Cygwin.

I need to do something slightly different according to the running environment and I came out with the following piece of code which is supposed to store in the variable a string which is `foo` if the OS is linux, otherwise `foo.exe`:

```
EXECUTABLE_FILENAME=bash -c 'os_type=`uname`; if [ $os_type == "Linux" ]; then echo "foo"; else echo "foo.exe"; fi'
```

then I would like to use that variable in another one, something like:

```
GODEPBUILD=$(godep go build -o $(EXECUTABLE_FILENAME))
```

the previous one with/without the evaluation via `$(...some stuff...)` (see below for all the tests I made to make this work)

finally I would like to "run" that command somewhere else in a task within the `makefile`, something like:

```
build-all:
   @echo -e "build my project"
   $(GODEPBUILD)
```

I have tried many different combinations

- with/without `$(some stuff here)`,
- with/without single quotes `'`,
- with/without the bash "`"
- with/without the wrap `bash -c '...some commands here...'`

but I get all sorts of bash errors e.g.:

- `invalid option -- 'c'`
- the `go` compiler complaining `EXECUTABLE_FILENAME` is empty with this message: `flag needs an argument: -o`
- silent ignore of the `$(GODEPBUILD)` (I believe because somehow it evaluates to an empty command)

I am doing this chain of steps because I need to wrap many commands of the `go` toolchain into another tool called `godep`, also I need to combine this with some specific features of the Operating System (e.g. the filename thing I am stuck with). I have defined many different "commands" of the `go` toolchain at the beginning of the `makefile` e.g.:

```
GODEP_VERSION=godep version
GODEPRESTORE=godep restore
GODEPTEST=godep go test -v
GOCLEAN=go clean
```

I call these "commands" inside the `makefile` tasks like `$(GODEP_VERSION)` (or `-$(GODEP_VERSION)` if I need to ignore the `stderr`) and for me it was nice to add the "build command" in a similar fashion.

The `make` version is:

- 4.1 on Ubuntu
- 4.2.1 on Cygwin

Is this thing possible at all?

How could I achieve this combination of different "small scripts" to build the final command that `make` should run inside a task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely you want the *output* of the bash command as the filename, right? You are using the bash command itself as the filename. i.e. `$(EXECUTABLE_FILENAME)` is a string consisting of several words. When you pass that to the `godep` command it gets passed as multiple arguments:

```
godep go build -o $(EXECUTABLE_FILENAME)
```

becomes:

```
godep go build -o bash -c 'os_type=`uname`; if [ s_type == "Linux" ]; then echo "foo"; else echo "foo.exe"; fi'
```

which is complete nonsense (note that `$o` gets expanded as a make variable, but that's the least of your problems).

Surely you want to *run* the bash command to decide the filename. You can run a shell command with make's `$(shell ...)` function:

```
EXECUTABLE_FILENAME = $(shell os_type=`uname` ; if [ $$os_type == Linux ]; then echo foo ; else echo foo.exe ; fi)
```

Note I used `$$os_type` to refer to a shell variable, so make doesn't try to expand `$os_type` before invoking the shell.

But I would simplify that to something like:

```
EXECUTABLE_FILENAME = foo$(shell [ `uname` == Linux ] || echo .exe)
```

Or maybe:

```
EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX = $(shell [ `uname` == Linux ] || echo .exe)
EXECUTABLE_FILENAME = foo$(EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX)
```

Now the make variable `$(EXECUTABLE_FILENAME)` will expand to the filename.

The next problem is here:

```
GODEPBUILD=$(godep go build -o $(EXECUTABLE_FILENAME))
```

What is this supposed to mean? Why have you enclosed it in `$(...)`? That tries to run a `make` function called `godep`, surely you just want:

```
GODEPBUILD = godep go build -o $(EXECUTABLE_FILENAME)
```

Then when you use it in the recipe it will expand to either:

```
build-all:
   @echo -e "build my project"
   godep go build -o foo
```

Or:

```
build-all:
   @echo -e "build my project"
   godep go build -o foo.exe
```

N.B. as an optional (but recommended) improvement you should use `:=` to set make variables, because otherwise they get expanded every time they are used. This would mean that every time you refer to a variable that uses `$(EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX)` the shell command is run again. Changing it to use `:=` will mean it gets evaluated once:

```
EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX := $(shell [ `uname` == Linux ] || echo .exe)
```

Similarly, you can use `:=` for the other variables too:

```
EXECUTABLE_FILENAME := foo$(EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX)
GODEPBUILD := godep go build -o $(EXECUTABLE_FILENAME)
```

(These ones don't really matter, as long as `EXECUTABLE_SUFFIX` used `:=` and so already contains the filename).

Comment: For some reason that I don't understand I had to use in the `if` statement a single `=` (rather than a double `==`) like this: >>>EXECUTABLE_FILENAME := $(shell os_type=\`uname\`; if [ $$os_type = "Linux" ]; then echo foo ; else echo foo.exe ; fi)<<<. This helped a bit in getting my head around `make` https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html I chose that "extended" version of the if/else because I still struggle when composing variables from other variables (to me all these rules look a bit over complicated), but thanks for pointing out alternative approaches :)